# How to delete every character after a space?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I am making a script that creates a backup of my `/home/` directory called `backup.sh`. When the backup completes I want the script to spit out the size of the backup in megabytes. Here are the lines I am having trouble with:

```
# creates an approximate size of the file + the file location
backup_text=$(du $new_backup)
# take off the file name at the end and add an 'M' to specify Megabytes
backup_text=${backup_text%[:blank:]*}M 
# print string to console
echo $backup_text
```

Here is the output I keep getting:

```
20 /backups/Thu_Aug_22_15:52M
```

As you can see, the backup size is 20M, which is correct, but the `/backups/...` part remains. What did I do wrong in my script?

Sorry, probably a noob question, just starting scripting =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the braces on your character class:

```
backup_text=${backup_text%[[:blank:]]*}M
```

The whole bracket expression (`[:blank:]`) counts as a single "character" (token) within a character class (`[...]`), so you need the brackets for both.

Answer (score 2):

### Replacement-Pattern Expansion

There are a number of ways to deal with this with [Bash pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), but I'd use [replacement expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin). For example:

```
$ shopt -u extglob
$ backup_text='foo bar'
$ echo ${backup_text/+([[:blank:]])*/}
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-h` option to get the size in a nice format instead of adding 'M'

Also, you don't need any magic to cut out the filename. Just get the first word!

And do not forget the quotes around `"$new_backup"`. This is **very** important because things will go wild if your `$new_backup` contains a space.

```
sizeStr=$(du -h "$new_backup" | awk '{print $1}')
```